# Beta rollout is not reaching the testers in Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

"Testers targeted by rollout" is appearing as zero for a closed Beta testing. No testers are seeing the new builds being uploaded, but are seeing the old build, when they visit PlayStore in their device.

**List of Testers Screen Shot**

[image: Screenshot]

I have created Closed Beta for release of an internal app. Checkbox is still ticked in the manage testers section for the group created for testers. Later, I also want to enable auto update for the testers.

**Zero testers targeted in the Rollout, Issue to be fixed screen shot**

[image: Screenshot]

I have added gmail id of 4 testers but "Testers targeted by rollout" is shown as zero and no tester is seeing new builds.

I am not able to distribute new builds of the app to the testers through - Closed Beta of Google Play console.

Comment: are you release app in beta testing or alpha testing?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

As shown by your screenshot it says "Testers: 0".
Even though you have added the testers, they need to opt in using the opt-in link. I'm guessing that they haven't done this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate two things to note here:

1. Your tester distribution list will have the email addresses of the testers.
2. In your screenshot there is an "opt-in" url, when they go to the opt-in url, on the Play Store app they need to be signed-in using the email they have been added as. If they have not selected it, it can be done using the square box (highlighted).

[image]